# How to get Python `unittest` `assertRaises` methods to print `msg` parameter?

Tags: python-unittest

In the following, the test should fail and print the `msg` parameter. But it doesn't.

```py
with self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError, msg="Unexpected denominator"):
    1/1
```

This parameter (`msg`) works in every other `assert*` method. It seems highly unlikely that something so fundamental could be broken in `unittest`, so what's the deal?

Here's a complete program that demonstrates the problem:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import unittest

class TestAssertRaisesMsgParam(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_assert_raises_msg(self):
        """
        Test unittest `assertRaises` msg param is printed
        """
        with self.assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError, msg="Unexpected denominator"):
            1/1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here's my interaction with it:

```
$ ls -l assertRaises.py
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tom users 440 Jun 10 14:04 assertRaises.py
$ python -m unittest assertRaises
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_assert_raises_msg (assertRaises.TestAssertRaisesMsgParam)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "assertRaises.py", line 14, in test_assert_raises_msg
    1/1
AssertionError: ZeroDivisionError not raised

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

And some system info:

```
$ /usr/bin/env python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Mar 22 2017, 12:31:17) [GCC] on linux2

$ uname -a
Linux ... 4.4.62-18.6-default #1 SMP Fri Apr 21 16:14:48 UTC 2017 (84f9824) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code works on my box:

```
$ python -m unittest tester
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_assert_raises_msg (test.TestAssertRaisesMsgParam)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danth\src\test.py", line 12, in test_assert_raises_msg
    1/1
AssertionError: ZeroDivisionError not raised : Unexpected denominator

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Make sure you run your test like this:

```
python -m unittest name_of_test_file
```

Comment: Hmm. I get different results. I guess it's some kind of platform problem.